# Solve recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relation, check-my-answer

> **A)** Solve this recurrence where $T(0)=0$ and write it in O-notation:
>   $T(n)= {2 \over n} (T(0)+T(1)+...+T(n-1))+c$

So, I started to calculate:

> $T(1)=2(0)+c=c$
>
> $T(2)=1(0+c)+c=2c$

and so on, which gives me that $T(n)=nc$

This I can prove by induction: $(n-1) \rightarrow n$

> $T(n)= {2 \over n} (0+c+2c+...+(n-1)c)+c = {2 \over n} (c{(n-1)n \over
>  2} )+c = nc$

Which gives me $O(n)$ (since $c$ is a constant). Am I right with this?

---

> **B)** For $T(n)=kT({n \over k})+ckn$ 
>   find the closed form for the function $T(n)=f(c,k,n)$ (I don't know what does this mean) and write it in
>   $\mathcal O$-notation.  If you had the algorithm working with $k=2$, $k=3$ or
>   $k=4$ which one would you choose?

I'm stuck with this problem. With the help of the master theorem, I would get $log_k k = 1$ which would give $\mathcal O(n \log n)$ but how to find the closed form?

Comment: If looks like $T(k^{m-1}) = mck^m$...

Comment: I don't understand this I'm afraid. Can you walk me through it?

Comment: $T(0) = kT(0) = 0$; $T(k^0) = kT(0)+ck = ck$; $T(k^1) = kT(1)+ck^2 = 2ck^2$ ... Of course, this isn't a complete solution.

Comment: You have two unrelated questions in your question.  Please, stick to one question per question.  For a., your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Comment: For b., please see our reference question, which shows how to solve such recurrence relations.  For what is meant by a "closed-form expression", see [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), and search for "closed form" in the search bar on this site in the upper right.  You'll find an answer there.  In the future please do more research before asking: if your questions can be answered in Wikipedia or through searching on this site or in standard textbooks, you haven't done enough research on your own before asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make life simple, assume $T(1)=1$. If we look at this just for integral powers of $k$, i.e. $n=k^m$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$, we have, by definition,
$$
T(k^m)=kT(k^{m-1})+ck\cdot k^m 
$$
We can repeatedly substitute into the recurrence to get:
$$\begin{align}
T(k^m)&=k\cdot{\color{red}{T(k^{m-1})}}+ck\cdot k^m\\
&=k\cdot{\color{red}{[k\cdot T(k^{m-2})+ck\cdot k^{m-1}]}}+ck\cdot k^m \\
&= k^2\cdot T(k^{m-2})+2ck\cdot k^m\\
&= k^3\cdot T(k^{m-3})+3ck\cdot k^m\\
&= k^4\cdot T(k^{m-4})+4ck\cdot k^m
\end{align}$$
and in general we have
$$
T(k^m) = k^j\cdot T(k^{m-j})+jck\cdot k^m
$$
which could be formally proved by induction.

The whole point of this *iterative expansion*, as it's known, is to drive the $T(\cdot)$ on the right side to a value we know, namely $T(1)$, so we'll let $j=m$ to obtain
$$
T(k^m) = k^m\cdot T(k^0)+mck\cdot k^m=k^m\cdot T(1)+mck\cdot k^m=k^m+mck\cdot k^m
$$
Finally, since we assumed that $n=k^m$, we have $m=\log_kn$ and the expression above becomes:
$$
T(n)=n+ckn\log_k n=n(1+ck\log_kn)
$$

For the next part, presumably you're being asked which of $k=2, 3, 4$ will make $T(\cdot)$ smallest. For example, which is eventually smaller, $2\log_2n$ or $3\log_3n$? You should be able to answer this with a modicum of effort.

Answer (score 6):

This is similar to the recurrence arising in the analysis of Quicksort, search for "quicksort analysis" to get lots of results.

An easy road is to write:
\begin{align}
(n + 1) T(n + 1) &= 2 \sum_{0 \le k \le n} T(k) + (n + 1) c \\
n T(n)           &= 2 \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} T(k) + n c
\end{align}
Subtract to get:
$$
(n + 1) T(n + 1) - (n + 2) T(n) = c
$$
This is a linear recurrence of the first order. Divide by $(n + 1) (n + 2)$ to get:
\begin{align}
\frac{T(n + 1)}{n + 2} - \frac{T(n)}{n + 1}
  &= \frac{c}{(n + 1) (n + 2)} \\
\sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1}
    \left( \frac{T(k + 1)}{k + 2} - \frac{T(k)}{k + 1} \right)
  &= c \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{1}{(k + 1) (k + 2)} \\
\frac{T(n)}{n + 1} - T(0)
  &= c \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k + 1} \right) \\
  &= c \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n + 1} \right) \\
  &= c \frac{n}{n + 1} \\
T(n)
  &= T(0) (n + 1) + c n
\end{align}